# Video still playing in html video element even after removing the video file

Tags: php, html, video

I am using the video element in html to play an mp4 file.

I am using a PHP file to export the video from a db and then play. The problem is that I have videos and images mixed in the db and I need to play on the fly either the video or show the image by pressing a single button, which it does. I used both img and video elements of html and I am deleting the current image and video that are last exported before exporting the new one and this should either show the image or the video when clicking the button, which it does for images.

When I try to export the video, it works and then when I try to show an image, both the image and the video are showing even though there is no video file anymore. The video gets unloaded after a minute or so.

My question would be why does the video still play even after the deletion of the mp4 file. I assume it stays in memory for a while. I tried clearing the cache and that doesn't work.

So how could I make sure the video doesn't play even after I delete the video file?

Comment: have a look in the browser developer tools... is the video being served from cache or network? if network and you're sure it's deleted on the server is there any other caching (eg ISP or a are you using service like CloudFlare) that may be delivering it?

Comment: the server is my computer, I'm using wamp. but if I delete the video from my pc it is still playing in the webpage for like 30 seconds after it's deleted.

Comment: if it's already playing and loaded on the page when you delete it, it will continue until it runs out of buffer